# MOSFET pins supports high currents?

Tags: mosfet

Several MOSFETs in TO220 package support continuous currents of 100 and up to 200 amps

For example, to handle currents of 50A, 6mm diameter cables are needed, how is it possible that such thick cables are attached to the pins of the MOSFET if these pins are 1mm wide?

I think that the temperature of the pins is dissipated by the same MOSFET and the respective heat sink, am I correct?

[image]

Comment: Don't trust the amp rating on the first page of MOSFET datasheets. Always calculate it for yourself. Those numbers are taken under conditions that are difficult to achieve in a real-circuit, in the real-world outside of a lab. Also, when you say 6mm diameter, I think are you including the insulation thickness.

Comment: _"Several MOSFETs in TO220 package support continuous currents of 100 and up to 200 amps"_ - evidence?

Comment: @BruceAbbott the datasheet of IRF1404... I have not tried it

Comment: Sometimes they are available in different packages, and the weaker packages don't support the full current the die can.

Comment: See note 6, package limits the current to 75A. And you would be hard-pressed to approach this due to thermal limitations.

Comment: The datasheet https://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=2350 does specify a TO-220AB package.

Comment: no, they don't. RTFDS. carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Read the datasheet carefully. For example the [IRF4104](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf1404.pdf?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss) has this:-

[image]

See that circled 6? That means note 6, which says:-

"Calculated continuous current based on maximum allowable junction temperature. **Package limitation current is 75A**."

> to handle currents of 50A, 6mm diameter cables are needed

Standard plastic insulated wire in a cable might be rated for 50 A ([this site](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) says 75 A for 'power transmission' and 158 A for 'chassis wiring') but MOSFET lead wires can safely run much hotter. Also the FET's rating is with appropriate cooling. The chip is rated for operation at 175 °C (so the package material must handle that) but with the **case temperature held at 25 °C**.

Bottom line is, ignore the absolute maximum ratings and keep the temperature down to a level that ensures *reliable* operation (eg 50°C). Depending on what cooling you have, that could be a lot less than 75 A. If you want low loss it might be lower again, eg. for 0.1 V drop the maximum current is only 25 A.

Comment: The answer is correct. Please also note that the package current limit is not due to the external pin but to the internal Al wire bonds. In the case of IRF1404 likely 3 wires of 350 um diameter. The self heating of this wires gives the the package limit.

Comment: "For bottom exposed part such as DPAK, TO220, D 2 PAK, there is always a note besides Id rating saying that Id is limited by **bonding wires**. Is this true? The answer is **no** for most of the cases." http://www.aosmd.com/res/application_notes/mosfets/continuous_drain.pdf

Comment: The AOD452 used in the app note is a relative high RDS Mosfet so may not follow in that case; in addition the usage of 220 C for Al wires is not considering the degradation of the mold compound around the wires, other suppliers use lower temperature.  But a lot of sub 4 mOhm mosfet are limited by wires: usually 75/80/120 A are used for D2PAK and TO220. DPAK are limited to 50/70/90 A depending on the wires.

Comment: MOSFETs with very low Rdson may be limited by bonding wires (app note says "to shift the hottest spot from silicon to wire, you need a silicon resistance around <1mohm."). The AOD452 is 6.5mOhm which is not much higher than the IRF1404. However we don't how the IRF1404 is bonded, so all we can say is that their **package** limits current.

Comment: May be you do not know, but others, working in the field, know something more. See similar on Paragraph 3.2 https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/20140428_appnote_MOSFET_Datasheet_explanation.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ed1d7b2011eee736f845470

Answer (score 2):

A TO-220 package is typically not connected to a cable.  Its soldered to a printed circuit board.  Transistor packages that are made to connect directly to wire typically have screw terminals on them for ring lugs.

Also note that wire ratings are designed around the idea that you have a really long piece of copper encased in an insulator.  If you make the piece of copper much shorter and take away the insulation things get a lot better.

- Thermal and electrical insulating properties of a material often strongly correlate.  A bare piece of metal in the air will loose heat to convection and radiation much more efficiently than one encased in rubber.
- Its not such a big problem if some spot in the middle of an un-insulated lead gets really hot.  We don't have to worry about melting insulation.  Instead we have to worry about the much higher melting point of copper and possibly the tin plating.
- If the leads are short, heat can conduct from the leads to the copper in the PCB.  This can considerably lower their temperature compared to the case of a really long bare wire of the same diameter.

Think about how much thinner the filament is inside of a glass fuse compared to the wire that would attach to that fuse.  The spot at the center of the fuse gets much hotter due to being so thin.  But it can be that hot because its not touching anything (like insulation) that will melt.